# Managing NordVPN extension in Chrome using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to automate a program and I need to change my VPN.
I did this with Browsec with no issues by downloading the extension pack and, through the html files in the Chrome Extension settings, nagivating throught the extension page like it was a normal webpage.

I am trying to do the same thing with NordVPN, but I encountered an issue. When I try to open the index.html file, which should show me the extension basic layout, i get this error:
**"Your browser is outdated. Please update your browser to use the NordVPN extension."**
I downloaded the last version of Chrome and the issue is still persisting.

Should I downgrade? To which version?
[This is the image of the error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPfWW.png)

Comment: Maybe Selenium is getting detected. Try using [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) or undetected-chromedriver

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii I am trying this manually right now to write the script and I'm getting this issue already :\

Comment: Oh I think you're not supposed to access it over the file-url. Usually, It's godda be something like `extension://some_long_id/popup.html`

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii Thanks! I was watching a guy do this and he opened it like normal the first time and then did this and I totally forgot it was a thing! Now it works properly